# Adding Integer To NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, nsnumber

I couldn't find this anywhere, so I am asking just asking to make sure.  And yes, I know its basic, but I figure I'd rather get that right before I make the mistake a million times:

If I do the following, does it cast the "0" to an NSNumber by default (if not, what Object type is it), or would I have to do the 2nd code?

(Or both of these could be wrong for what I'm trying to do.  If so, let me know.  They both compile so I am just wondering which one is "right" (or preferred) and why.)

Code 1:

```
NSMutableArray array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
[array addObject: 0];
```

Code 2:

```
NSMutableArray array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` *doesn't take primitive types*.

> The second option is correct.

Comment: Okay cool.  Thank you!! I'll flag this as the right answer soon (it says I have to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer to this question)

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help.

Comment: what id I have variable to add

Answer (score 8):

You cannot put a primitive such as an `int` into an `NSArray`; you must construct an `NSNumber` instance to hold it.

> If I do the following, does it cast the "0" to an NSNumber by default (if not, what Object type is it)

No casting takes place. It's not possible to simply "cast" a primitive into an object, and the primitive does not have an object type. Objects must be constructed by sending messages (except: see below), which happens at runtime; casting only has an effect during compilation.

The only reason this works is that you have chosen `0` to add to the array. This is the same value as `nil`, which stands for "no object". If you had chosen any other integer, you would have a crash on your hands when you ran the code, since the value would be used as a pointer to memory that doesn't hold a valid object.

Interestingly, though, starting with Clang 3.1 or Apple's LLVM 4.0,* there is [some new syntatical sugar](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for creating objects from literals in code. We've always had literal `NSStrings`: `@"Lichtenstein"`. With the new compiler, other objects can likewise be created using the `@` character.

In this case, to create an `NSNumber` object from a literal integer, you can simply write:

```
[array addObject:@0];
```

---

*<sub>(not yet available in public Xcode)</sub>

Comment: still not yet available in public Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the previous replies, you can only add objects (`id` type) to container classes like `NSArray`.

One class that can be helpful in this context is `NSValue`, which serves as a container for non-object data types of C and objective-C. In addition to numerical data types, this can also contain structs and some objective-C primitive data types like `NSRect`.

Look here for more details:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html